# DialogFlow actions-on-google: followup how to set expectUserInput to false

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, webhooks

When I want to go back to my "welcome" event, the assistant asks me to "try to give the brand again" instead of going to the event. After I give the brand again, it switches to the welcome intent.

I think I need to set `expectUserInput` to `false` but I can't seem to find where I can set this property.
In the simulator under the response tab, you can find the `expectUserInput` set to `true`. But I don't want this because it is an unnecessary and annoying step. I've tried setting `conv.expectUserInput = false;` but that didn't work.

```
app.intent("PickBrand", (conv, parameters) => {

  if (isAskedToStop(parameters.StopSigns)) {

    conv.followup("welcome");

  } else {

    item.brand = parameters.Brands;
    conv.ask(
      `<speak>Which appliance do you need from ${item.brand}?</speak>`
    );
  }
});
```

```
const isAskedToStop = (userInput) => {
  if (userInput.includes("stop") || userInput.includes("back") || userInput.includes("break") || userInput.includes("begin")) return true;
}
```

[ExpectUserInput inside the response tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrgmb.png)

Comment: If you set expectUserResponse to false the conversation will end, you can do it by calling conv.close("Ending message goes here"), but from you description it doesn't seem that you want the conversation to end.

Comment: yes I don't want the conversation to end. I want to skip the part where the assistant asks me to give the brand again before going to my default welcome intent (welcome event)

Comment: I think what you want instead is a different intent that can be handled similarly but isn't exactly the Welcome.

Comment: allright thanks, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of issues with your approach that may be causing you problems.

First of all, remember that an Intent represents *what the user has said* and **not** what you're trying to do. An Intent is not a function. So saying that you "want to go back to the welcome intent" is unclear - the welcome Intent is an event that indicates that the user has started your Action. How you *respond* to that is up to you.

Similarly, how you *respond* to anything the user has does is up to you. If the user indicates that they want to start over (in some way), you can respond by asking the initial questions again.

Typically this is done through an Intent that captures phrases such as "I want to start over" or "let's begin again". Which leads to the second issue with what you're trying to do - parsing the user's text in your Intent Handler.

You don't show the phrases that you're using in your "PickBrand" Intent, but they sound fairly broad. Normally I would expect that the PickBrand Intent would be triggered by phrases such as:

- The *brand name* one sounds good
- Let's go with *brand name*
- *brand name*

If you expected the user to ask further questions about a brand, you might have a different Intent capturing phrases such as

- How does this compare to
- What is the price?

Or you may split these up into even more different Intents. Regardless, you'd probably have a completely different Intent picking up phrases such as

- Can we start over?
- Let me look at *appliance type* now?
- What about something else?

Trying to capture these by searching for words in a phrase in your code can lead to a number of problems - better to let a Natural Language Processing system such as Dialogflow handle them for you, and boil them down into an Intent.

Once you get the Intent, of course, you can handle them however you want. If they ask to start over - you may wish to confirm that, or you may wish to just start over by clearing out all the state you have about what they were looking at before. (You may wish to save it, in case they say something like "how does this compare to that other *appliance type*?".) But that is all up to you.